airflow dynamic task mapping doesn't work
I have the following DAG which should spawn as many tasks as specified in the variable, but the mapped tasks tab shows "No Data found":
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

from airflow.decorators import dag, task

from airflow.models import Variable


@dag(schedule=None, start_date=datetime(2024, 11, 15), catchup=False)
def test_autoscaling():

    @task()
    def consume_mem(mem_to_consume: int, index: int):
        print(f'consuming {mem_to_consume} bytes in task {index}')
        with open('/dev/urandom', 'rb') as f:
            rand_data = f.read(mem_to_consume)
            sleep(600)

    num_tasks = int(Variable.get('num_tasks'))
    mem_to_consume = int(Variable.get('mem_to_consume'))
    consume_mem.partial(mem_to_consume=mem_to_consume).expand(index=list(range(num_tasks)))


test_autoscaling()

Why aren't tasks dynamically created?

Oh dear.... my awful newb mistake. There was nothing wrong with the DAG. The start_date was in the future...
